# how to add another project in my existing Android Studio project?

Tags: android

I'm getting some image cropping demo from the net , and I'm trying to import that lib project in my existing android studio project. I don't understand how to import lib project in my project .

Here is getting demo from net.

[image]

See this is highlighted the folder name cropper . This demo is getting from net .How to done same as in my existing project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to File->New->Import Module then browse you project. After importing module go to project structure and add module dependency to your project.

Answer (score 1):

First add it as a new module into your project.

Then go to Project structure select dependencies tab and then add that module as a dependenci.