# How to merge source code from 2 project Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Very sorry if my questions are stupid. 
After searching, I get the source code of 2 open source projects. Somewhat difficult to describe, but it is an assistant app instead of google assistant. A project is similar to the framework for the assistant, and the other project that receives information from the assistant to search. I want to put two projects into one and export a single apk.
It's hard to get started, so please help me.

Comment: include framework project as a module in your main project

Comment: Can you give specific instructions? Because the two projects output 2 apk files, and to perform all the functions, both apk files must be installed.

Comment: when you will merge 2 codes, then it should output a single apk.

Comment: Please teach me how to merge 2 source code. I do not know where to start. please give me a keyword

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223028/how-to-add-another-project-in-my-existing-android-studio-project

Comment: Will I have to convert framework project it into a library module?

Comment: yes that's what I was saying. Import that project as a new module in your main project.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your old project in the new as a module. See the following instructions.

1. Find your old project folder by right-clicking on the project name
   in the "Package Explorer" -> Properties -> "Location".
2. Open your
   new project, go to File -> New -> Import Module, browse "Location"
   path and choose your project.
3. Go to Project structure ->
   Dependencies tab and then add that module as a dependency.