# Android Studio - Importing Project as Module not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and got two projects I want to merge into one. I thought of importing one as module into the other but it's not working since the finish button remains greyed out.

Here is what it's looking like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbeTL.jpg

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223028/how-to-add-another-project-in-my-existing-android-studio-project helps?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't solve the problem because it's just a tutorial how to add a module and set dependencies. I know how to import a module but the actual problem is that I can't finish the import because the button is greyed out.