# Android build Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, build.gradle

i tried to use shinebutton api (https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton)

However, the following error appears during the build phase :(

It is an error that has not occurred before and occurs after adding code to gradle.

help me

error : `Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.`

code : `implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 1):

`ShineButton` uses `com.daasuu:EasingInterpolator:1.3.0` dependency for animation effects and this dependency has been upgraded to `1.3.2` (see [EasingInterpolator in GitHub](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/EasingInterpolator)) but ShineButton` has not updated his dependency while many have noticed to the author. (see [here](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton/issues)). So this library won't work until the author updates the dependency.

You can download the source file and fix the dependency version then follow this post.
[how to add another project in my existing Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35223028/6576302)